# Delete Full S3 Bucket CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to delete an S3 bucket that has some objects in it:

```
aws s3 rb --force  s3://ansible.prod-us-east 
remove_bucket failed: s3://ansible.prod-us-east An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.
```

I also tried this:

```
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket "ansible.prod-us-east" --region "us-east-1" 

An error occurred (BucketNotEmpty) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.
```

The errors say that the bucket is full. But when I list it on the command line or look at the bucket in the console the bucket is already empty.

I get the same error when I try to delete the bucket from the console. The bucket is empty but the error says that it's full and I can't delete the bucket.

How can I get this done?

Comment: You have to delete every object in the bucket first.

Comment: In case the bucket has versions, you need to delete them as well

Comment: OK thanks. I will!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The errors say that the bucket is full. But when I list it on the
>   command line or look at the bucket in the console the bucket is
>   already empty.

It is a versioned bucket. In AWS Console, by default, Versions are hidden. You have an option to show the versioned objects and delete markers. To view the versions in CLI,

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket ansible.prod-us-east
```

To delete the bucket, all the versions and the delete markers must be deleted first. It is easier to get this done in `boto3` than `aws-cli`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('ansible.prod-us-east')
bucket.object_versions.all().delete()
bucket.delete()
```

Try [this](https://gist.github.com/weavenet/f40b09847ac17dd99d16), if you want to get this done with `aws s3api`.

Comment: +1. I think interesting to note here is that even using `--force` with `aws s3 rb` will not work with versioned bucket.

Comment: thanks for the shell script. Saved me some good tedious hours. Bless u